# RSAenryption java

Tags: java, rsa

I have this task:

> Create a constructor that takes a key pair instead of randomly generating a new set. These keys pairs will include the modulous and exponent for both public and private keys.

What am I doing wrong here? I know it says not to use random but how else can I do it?

```
private BigInteger key;
  private BigInteger p;
  private BigInteger q;
  private BigInteger eulerTotient;
  private BigInteger e;
  private BigInteger n;
  private BigInteger d;
  public Ramdom rdm1;

public RSAEncryption()
{


  p = BigInteger.probablePrime(256, rdm1);
  q = BigInteger.probablePrime(255, rdm1);
  //Calculating an n value by multiplying p and q
  n = p.multiply(q);

  //Turning the number one into a BigInteger for assistance
  BigInteger one =  BigInteger.valueOf(1);

  //Euler totient is (p -1) * (q-1)
  eulerTotient = p.subtract(one).multiply(q.subtract(one));

  //e is some number between 1 and the totient
  e = BigInteger.probablePrime(511, rdm1);
  this.e = e;

  //d is the private key and calculated as inverse of e modulous totient
  d = (e.modInverse(eulerTotient));
  this.d = d;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your function doesn't take a key pair, as requested; instead, it generates the values (e.g., `p = BigInteger.probablePrime(256, rdm1);`). Your function needs to accept parameters, instead of generating new values.

Comment: i am basically trying to generate key for it. i need to use modulous and exponent as my parameters. i kinda of generate those in my constructor with out parameters. I'm just confused with whole thing.

Comment: You might want to read [this basic tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). In short, you need to write `RSAEncryption` so it accepts two parameters, `p` and `q`, instead of generating them with `BigInteger.probablePrime()`.

Comment: ahh i think it makes sense. I should do math using given values In parameter. thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer that I think will help.

Comment: "...How else can I do it...". What, exactly, is "it"? What is this constructor supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know what `Ramdom ` is (besides a typo), but if it isn't a cryptographically secure random then you are possibly in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments, the problem is that `BigInteger` doesn't take a key pair, as requested; instead, it generates the values (e.g., `p = BigInteger.probablePrime(256, rdm1);`). Your constructor needs to accept parameters, instead of generating new values. So, you need to write `RSAEncryption` so it accepts two parameters, `p` and `q`, instead of generating them with `BigInteger.probablePrime()`.

Here's some (untested) sample code that should help you along the way in rewriting the constructor:

```
public RSAEncryption(BigInteger p, BigInteger q) // note the parameters
{
  /**
   * I deleted the assignments here. Because you get p and q as parameters,
   * theres's no need for probablePrime()
   */

  //Calculating an n value by multiplying p and q
  n = p.multiply(q);

  //Turning the number one into a BigInteger for assistance
  BigInteger one =  BigInteger.valueOf(1);

  //Euler totient is (p -1) * (q-1)
  eulerTotient = p.subtract(one).multiply(q.subtract(one));

  //e is some number between 1 and the totient
  e = BigInteger.probablePrime(511, rdm1);
  this.e = e;

  //d is the private key and calculated as inverse of e modulous totient
  d = (e.modInverse(eulerTotient));
  this.d = d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a constructor that directly sets `n`, `d` and `e`. The other values are intermediate values so you should probably not store them in fields (unless you have to implement Chinese Remainer Theorem private key calculations later on, then you should store `p`, `q` and a few other values).

So that would be:

```
public RSAEncryption(BigInteger n, BigInteger d, BigInteger e) {
    this.n = n;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
}
```

any other fields will be set to `null` if you call this constructor.

The above will be enough to set the key pair consisting of the private key (n, d) and the public key (n, e). It's of course not required to pass `n` twice.

This is only useful if you have to implement the RSA calculations yourself. If you want to use the Java JCA/JCE then you can simply pass [a `KeyPair` object instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html) consisting of an `RSAPublicKey` and `RSAPrivateKey` or just the public and private key objects themselves.